# How to fill input field automatically when name is selected from database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have a form that need to be filled up, one of its field is employee name, I selected its value from a database table called tbl_employee, each name has codename that stored in the same table, but I have a problem, because I dont know what code to be used to automatically filled the input field called codename. the following is my html code

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Employee Name</label>
  <select name="employee" onchange="getEmp(this.value)" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Employee</option>
    <?php foreach($emps as $emp) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $emp["employee_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $emp["surname"] . ', ' . $emp["firstname"]; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Code Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="codenamer" type="text"/>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

your response is highly appreciated

Comment: `<input class="form-control" name="codenamer" type="text" value="<?php echo $codename; ?>"/>` something like this

Comment: you are getting the list of employees, how we know which one is the selected or to select ?

Comment: now u have 2 solutions, try them and accept the best one.

Comment: @romain B. thanks for reply, i will try this right now

Answer (score 0):

To give the input a value, you add the "value" attribute to it:

`<input class="form-control" name="codenamer" type="text" value="<?php echo $emp["codename"]; ?>" />`

Comment: Will not work currently because `$emp` is defined inside a loop. But that's it if you ommit that point.

Comment: i used this code but it only display one value, not a value that associates with the employee

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery here:

**First** of all pass codename column in `option` value:

```
<select name="employee" onchange="getEmp(this.value)" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Employee</option>
    <?php foreach($emps as $emp) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $emp["codename "]; ?>"> // use codename column in value here.
        <?php echo $emp["surname"] . ', ' . $emp["firstname"]; ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

**Second**, add a ID attribute on your input field:

```
<input class="form-control" name="codenamer" type="text" id="codenamer" />
```

**Than**, you can use jQuery to add the value on your input field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getEmp(codename){
        $("#codenamer").val(codename); // add value to codenamer field.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sir based on your comment // use codename column in value here., is there something that i need to add on that line?

Comment: @n-jay just value which u need to populate in input field automatically

Comment: I used this line $("#codenamer").val($emp["codename "]); is this correct sir?

Comment: @N-Jay: u cant pass php inside jquery.

Comment: try as i shared @N-Jay

Comment: your code doesn't change the output, however i'm still grateful for your response.

Comment: @N-Jay: can u please share the updated code which not working.

Comment: it's now working sir, I posted the code as answer to my question, thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without reloading the page, you need Javascript.

First, add the codename into the option attributes that you generate with PHP:

```
<option data-codename="<?= $emp['codename'] ?>" value="<?= $emp["employee_id"]; ?>"><?= $emp["surname"] . ', ' . $emp["firstname"]; ?></option>
```

Then in JS, check whenever the selected option changes, extract the codename from the selected option and write its `data-codename` into the value of your codenamer input.

Something like this (using Jquery):

```
$('#employee-selector').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

    var codename = selected.attr('data-codename');

    //if the above fails, you may have to use this: (note the [0])
    //var codename = selected[0].attr('data-codename');

    $('#codenamer').val(codename);
});
```

This requires you to put `id='employee-selector'` on your select element and `id='codenamer'` on your codenamer input field.

Comment: OP is idle now :)

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm gonna try all codes that posted here.

Comment: @William I used your code sir, but it displays a codename automatically, but not the codename associates when employees name.and i dont udertsand where to place (note the [0], it would be better if you tell me what exactly to do.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is already solve. i've just rephrase the codes given above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getEmp(codename){
         var res = codename.split(" ", 1 );
        document.getElementById("codenamer").value=res;
    }
</script>
```

and caller to my input field

```
id="codenamer"
```

thanks to all respondent.

Comment: accept your answer, this will help to future visitor,