# How to automatically fill the input field in html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a system project where I can create fuel expenses records, so the process to create an expenses records, I fill up the first form with names of employee,

here's my first form:(using this form, I can access all employee's name from database)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Employee Name</label>
     <select name="employee" onchange="getEmp(this.value)" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Select Employee</option>
          <?php foreach($emps as $emp) : ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $emp["employee_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $emp["surname"] . ', ' . $emp["firstname"]; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
   <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

the name of employee is already stored in the table named tbl_employee, each names are provided with codename and  issued with vehicle. so in other words, I have two tables in my database named, tbl_employee and tbl_vehicle.
the tbl_employee has attribute: employee_id(primary key), carid(foreign key) surname, firstname and codename,

the tbl_vehicle has attribute: carid(primary key) and reg_num(registration number or plate number)

what I want is, when I select a names from the form stated above, I want to automatically fill the form (stated below) with its codename and a reg_num(plate number):

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Employees Code Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="codename" type="text"/>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Plate Number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="reg_num" type="text"/>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
```

I also using this SQL statement to access the employees name directly from the database:

```
$emp = query("SELECT * FROM tbl_employee");
render("./fuel/list.php", ["title" => "Fuel Expenses List", "fuels" => $rows, "emps" => $emp]);
```

as you see, there is no javascript written on my codes, that's one of the reason why I need everyone's help.

Comment: I looked at the other thread of yours, William's answer is what you want. What's the problem that you have with that answer?

Comment: What makes you think you will get a proper answer this time? since from what I see, those are well-explained answers on your other question :  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54986735/8566549

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience sir, i tried those codes, but it doesn't work, it runs no error but the output is not what i wanted. I badly need to ask it again because this time it includes an attribute's value that stored from different table.

Comment: Please update this question, added the code you tried and explain in details what output you expect and what is the actual output, then we can help. People can't help you with "output is not I want"

Comment: Please share the javascript code as well

Comment: I have no javascript written for that function sir. I dont know how to do it.

Comment: @HastaDhana I will still review that codes sir,

Comment: @catcon i have revised my question sir, I hope you will get my point.

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
onkeyup(getEmp(this.value));
```

Comment: Instead of try this, kindly explain your answer. It will help future reader as well.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22382693)